# How to rerender .map() list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to rerender a list when I click a button that sends the first element of the array to the last position, however, when I click the button the component doesn't rerender, even thou the console.log shows that the array has changed:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-zo3rn?file=/DailyScheduler.js:0-832)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const DailySchedule = () => {
  const [exerciseList, setExerciseList] = useState([
    "exercise 1",
    "exercise 2",
    "exercise 3"
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <h2>Warm-up</h2>

        <ul>
          {exerciseList.map((exrcs, idx) => {
            return (
              <li>
                {exrcs}{" "}
                {idx === 0 && (
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      exerciseList.push(exerciseList.shift());
                      setExerciseList(exerciseList);
                      console.log(exerciseList);
                    }}
                  >
                    Done
                  </button>
                )}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DailySchedule;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the array reference in state is not changed. Update the setState call like this,

```
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              exerciseList.push(exerciseList.shift());
              setExerciseList([...exerciseList]);
              console.log(exerciseList);
            }}
          >
            Done
          </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because you're modifying the `exerciseList` array directly, which you shouldn't do, as the state update will see that the list is the same and not trigger a re-render. Instead make a copy of the array, and then use `setExerciseList`:

```
const newList = [...exerciseList]
newList.push(newList.shift())
setExerciseList(newList)
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because array reference is not changed.

```js
  onClick={() => {
    const list = [...exerciseList]
    list.push(list.shift());
    setExerciseList(list);
  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the array reference to reflect that in the state.

```
setExerciseList([...exerciseList]);
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-ohl1u

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you're mutating your state directly by using `.push()` and `.shift()`. This is a "no-no" in the react-world. Instead, you can treat your array as immutable by not changing your original state, but rather by producing a new array so that your state will update correctly. One approach to do this is to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the first item from your array and obtain the rest of your array in an array called `rest`, then set your new state using the destructured variables using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`):

```
onClick={() => setExerciseList(([first, ...rest]) => [...rest, first])}
```